# How to update multiple secondary tiles using background agent in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to update data on several secondary tiles in a windows phone 8 application. I am using a BackGround Agent to update the tiles.

```
 IconicTileData tileData = new IconicTileData
        {
            IconImage = new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
            Title = "My Tile title",
            Count = new Random().Next(1, 10),
        };

        ShellTile mainTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
        if (mainTile != null)
        {
            mainTile.Update(tileData);
        }

        // If debugging is enabled, launch the agent again in one minute.
#if DEBUG_AGENT
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
```

Here it is to update the mainTile data. But how can I find how many secondary tiles are pinned and how to update them individually?

Answer (score 1):

Frok the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.activetiles%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for `ShellTile.ActiveTiles`: This list includes an Application Tile, which cannot be deleted, and all of its Secondary Tiles. The Application Tile is always the first in the collection.

So:

```
foreach (var tile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
{
    //update the tile
}
```

Comment: That was fine but how to identify each tile? Like first tile has one data and second has another !!

Comment: so take a look at the `tile` variable, use the debugger, show some effort

Comment: I tried what you said but I couldn't find the method to find the data on the tile. please help

Answer (score 0):

As you know each tile has some Navigation URI.You can search for unique word in the query string of Navigation URI.

```
ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("unique key/value in querystring"));
```

In this way you can identify all secondary tiles by iterating through them and checking the Navigation URI.